# why does scipy linprog give me different result(s) when I run the solver

Tags: optimization, scipy, scipy-optimize

below are my values for A,b and c

```
A = [[-0.07017000000000008,
  -0.06875000000000009,
  -0.08124999999999982,
  -0.07874999999999988,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.07125000000000004,
  -0.10000000000000007,
  -0.08000000000000007,
  -0.08250000000000003,
  -0.08000000000000007,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.0887500000000001,
  -0.08749999999999991,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-1.035085,
  -1.06875,
  -0.08124999999999982,
  -1.07875,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.07125000000000004,
  -0.10000000000000007,
  -0.08000000000000007,
  -0.08250000000000003,
  -0.08000000000000007,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.0887500000000001,
  -0.08749999999999991,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-0.0,
  -0.0,
  -1.040625,
  -0.0,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.07125000000000004,
  -0.10000000000000007,
  -0.08000000000000007,
  -0.08250000000000003,
  -0.08000000000000007,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.0887500000000001,
  -0.08749999999999991,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -1.038125,
  -1.07125,
  -0.10000000000000007,
  -1.08,
  -0.08250000000000003,
  -0.08000000000000007,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.0887500000000001,
  -0.08749999999999991,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -1.05,
  -0.0,
  -0.08250000000000003,
  -1.08,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.0887500000000001,
  -0.08749999999999991,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -1.0825,
  -0.0,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.07249999999999979,
  -0.0887500000000001,
  -0.08749999999999991,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -1.03625,
  -1.0724999999999998,
  -1.08875,
  -0.08749999999999991,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.08749999999999991,
  -0.07624999999999993,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -1.04375,
  -1.038125,
  -0.08999999999999986],
 [-0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -0.0,
  -1.045]]
```

```
b = [-8404.290720230543,
 -7978.821598597756,
 -7578.708024495149,
 -7183.238648226586,
 -6786.842429275058,
 -6391.750401843791,
 -6004.298886236267,
 -5628.459517399929,
 -5265.81063108901,
 -4916.495176141842]
```

```
c = [1.04783,
 1.05205,
 1.109,
 1.07845,
 1.1587399999999999,
 1.15271,
 0.9643,
 1.15447,
 1.16534,
 1.20881,
 1.2155200000000002,
 1.2556100000000001,
 1.3947399999999999,
 1.396,
 1.38096,
 1.46286]
```

when I run the optimiser

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
sol = linprog(c,A,b)
```

I keep getting one of these two output(s) (randomly!). Newbie to optimisation so anyone could explain why this is happening? I keep getting the same result for a while before it flips to the other output. As I said that has been an element of randomness in the output.

```
con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 117141.7162281064
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 12
   slack: array([-4.67044993e-06,  4.25469153e+02,  8.25582701e+02,  1.22105209e+03,
        2.71663406e+04,  8.83254052e-06,  5.97474263e-06, -2.56032490e-06,
        5.72461833e+04,  1.70035340e-04])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1.17529749e-05, 1.12090811e-05, 1.32910234e-05, 1.37475228e-05,
       1.01747330e-05, 9.24745414e-06, 2.68935708e+04, 1.12870733e-05,
       6.76816787e+02, 9.81354410e-06, 7.39541248e-04, 1.05819501e-04,
       3.45201835e+02, 5.94860490e+04, 2.61213519e-05, 4.70478024e+03])
```

```
con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 103625.40354369869
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 12
   slack: array([-9.96078597e-08,  4.25469122e+02,  8.25582696e+02,  1.22105207e+03,
        2.71663406e+04,  3.22534106e-07,  8.86870657e-06, -3.39969120e-08,
        5.72461835e+04,  4.47840375e-06])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([1.89807107e-07, 1.70280271e-07, 1.67619035e-07, 1.59598716e-07,
       1.56527456e-07, 1.27125074e-07, 2.68935708e+04, 4.27355248e-07,
       6.76816767e+02, 3.78644980e-07, 2.45305378e-07, 2.49666428e-07,
       3.45202643e+02, 5.94860493e+04, 5.70831628e-07, 4.70478008e+03])
```

Comment: Show a minimal reproducible code-example resulting in this. **As the objective is different, it's a bug**. Either on your end or the solvers end. There might be other sources of indeterminism (rather the rule than the exception due to multithreading and non-associative fp-math) though. But that's not much relevant here (for now).

Comment: Which version of scipy are you using?  You can check with `import scipy; print(scipy.__version__)`

Comment: @sascha I suppose that the code you talking about? from scipy.optimize import linprog
sol = linprog(c,A,b)

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser version is 1.4.1

Comment: I cannot replicate that behavior.  With `scipy` version 1.5.2 and your values of A,b,c above I get a function value of 117128.6... every time.  There is something going on in the namespace you are working in.  If you are in a notebook or such, pop your code into a text editor and run it separately or ...?

Comment: thanks @AirSquid, interesting - just ran on my Mac and I get your number, but on my work windows laptop am getting those two outputs randomly. my Mac has 1.7 and work laptop upgraded to version 1.5.4